# Throw err exception while running a simple server in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, client

Iam running a simple web server with basic send and receive operations to be performed.Here the main aim of this basic server file is to start the listner of the server on some port and we have to connect a client to this port and a Hello World Message is displayed.But when i run the file there is **throw** error occuring.The code is shown below

```
var db, http, onRequest ,portnum, restFunc ,returncode;

db = require('db');
db.init();

portnum =3000;

//rest function goes here

onRequest =function (req , res) {
    var bodyStr ='';
    //function is called for each chunck of data received
    req.on('data',function(chunck) {
        bodyStr += chunck.toString();
    });

    //function is called when all the data has been received
    //request has been sent now build respons   
    req.on('end',function() {
        var argArray ,buflen ,contenttype ,outobj ,outputStr,recid;

        outputStr = "Hello World<br>\n";
        outputStr +="method:" +req.method +"\n";
        outputStr += "Posted data is: " + bodyStr + "\n";

        res.end(outputStr);
    });
}





http = require("http");
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(portnum);

console.log("Server started ,listening on port#" +portnum);
```

The error Log is as follows

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'db'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\basic_server.js:3:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

After this error i tried to install missing **db** package using npm but still the error remains same.

```
C:\Users\Sai Kiran>npm install db
db@1.0.6 node_modules\db
├── ds@1.2.0
├── redis@0.6.7
├── mysql@0.9.4 (hashish@0.0.4)
└── aws-sdk@0.9.7-pre.8 (xmlbuilder@8.2.2, xml2js@0.2.4)
```

Comment: When i did npm install error C:\Users\Sai Kiran>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies

Comment: Did you run **npm install db** in the project's folder? I mean is your project's root placed under "C:\Users\Sai Kiran>"?

Comment: couldn't read dependencies? do you have a package.json?

Comment: Ya but same error repeats

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal i did npm install and some error message came that it isn't a repo and you dont have package.json file

Comment: run 'npm init' then 'npm install db --save'. In the future, if you install some packages, use the --save key, so installed package will be added to you package.json

Comment: you have express installed? try this `express <some application name>` then get in the created directory and run `npm install --save db`

Comment: Sorry guys for troubling you  @AmreshVenugopal the server was not started after i installed the package.Now i closed the server and restarted the server and now no errors.Thanks

Comment: @AlexeyPedyashev i did not restarted the server.Small mistakes cost much